# Add a class for checkbox if it's value is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want to add a new class to the specific checkbox if its value is changed, but I have so many checkbox I don't know how to set up the trigger.

here's what I got so far:

```
 $( "I dont know what to put here since I have lots of checkbox" )
      .change(function() 
    {
      $(this).addClass("edited");
    }
 );
```

Edit: I generate the checkbox in a table through ajax :

```
$("#ButtonLR").click(function () {
//stopwatch
var start = window.performance.now();

$("#getData").empty();

// display loading bar.
$("#getData").append("<div id='loadingBar'></div>");

var projects = [];

$("#CheckBoxListProjects").find("input:checked").each(function () {
    projects.push(this.value);
});
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Ajax/GetData.ashx",
    data: { projects: projects},
    dataType: "json",
})
.done(function (data) {
    var count = updateDataTable(data).count

});
```

});

Here's the function that generates table contain checkboxs, isapproved and ignore are checkboxs.

```
function updateDataTable(data) {
// Clear the data table.
var count = 0;
$("#getData").empty();

// Create new data table.
$("#getData").append("<div id='resources'></div>");

// Create header for data table.
$("#resources").append("<div>" +
    "<span class='noedit'>" + "Project" + "</span>" +
    "<span class='noedit'>" + "IsApproved" + "</span>" +
    "<span class='noedit'>" + "Ignore" + "</span>" +
    "</div>");
$("#getData").append("<div id='resources'></div>");
// For each item, append to data table.
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    if (item["IsApproved"] == true) {
        item["ApproveCheck"] = "<input type='checkbox' checked>";
    }
    else {
        item["ApproveCheck"] = "<input type='checkbox'>";
    }
    if (item["ParserError"] == true) {
        item["Ignore"] = "<input type='checkbox' checked>";
    }
    else {
       item["Ignore"] = "<input type='checkbox'>";
    }

    $("#resources").append("<div>" +
   "<span'>" + item["ProjectFile"] + "</span>" +
   "<span'>" + item["ApproveCheck"] + "</span>" +
   "<span'>" + item["Ignore"] + "</span>" +
   "</div>");
    }
    count++;
});

return {
    count: count,

};
```

}

I want checkbox IsApproved and Ignore to addclass 'edited' after the value is changed.

Comment: show your html please

Comment: How does the checkbox your talking about differ from the other checkboxes on your page? Does it have its own ID or Class?

Comment: @spryno724 *'but I have so many checkbox'* Your selector would affect all checkboxes

Comment: @George Right, but that is all the info we have...

Comment: can you share the html for the target checkbox

Comment: @spryno724 so you shouldn't jump to conclusion!

Comment: which one of them do you want the class to be added to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use event delegation ... To select only the second and third checkboxes (as these seem to be the ones in question):

```
$(document).on("change", "#resources div > span:nth-child(2) > input[type=checkbox], #resources div > span:nth-child(3) > input[type=checkbox]", function() {
    $(this).addClass("edited");
});
```

This will append the class to only the second and third checkboxes inside your `span`s when receiving the `change` event.

Comment: this will affect all the checkboxes and that is not what the OP wants

Comment: the first sentence of the question "I want to add a new class to the specific checkbox"

Comment: This would do the job. Nothing else to add.

Comment: @AminJafari Edited in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a class "checkbox" for your checkboxes and then use:

```
$( ".checkbox" ).change(function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "edited" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work

```
//I assume you want al checkbox in #getData to have this behaviour
//Use a class for your checkboxes, I used .checkbox, is better than using input[type=...
$('#getData').find('.checkbox').on('change', function () {
    $(this).addClass('my-class');
});
```

You can use event delegation for performance is the table is big.

Answer (score 1):

you could do the following:

Add a `data-edit` to the inputs you wanna add the class to after they're edited:

```
function updateDataTable(data) {
// Clear the data table.
var count = 0;
$("#getData").empty();

// Create new data table.
$("#getData").append("<div id='resources'></div>");

// Create header for data table.
$("#resources").append("<div>" +
    "<span class='noedit'>" + "Project" + "</span>" +
    "<span class='noedit'>" + "IsApproved" + "</span>" +
    "<span class='noedit'>" + "Ignore" + "</span>" +
    "</div>");
$("#getData").append("<div id='resources'></div>");
// For each item, append to data table.
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    if (item["IsApproved"] == true) {
        item["ApproveCheck"] = "<input type='checkbox' checked data-edit='true'>";
    }
    else {
        item["ApproveCheck"] = "<input type='checkbox'>";
    }
    if (item["ParserError"] == true) {
        item["Ignore"] = "<input type='checkbox' checked>";
    }
    else {
       item["Ignore"] = "<input type='checkbox' data-edit='true'>";
    }

    $("#resources").append("<div>" +
   "<span'>" + item["ProjectFile"] + "</span>" +
   "<span'>" + item["ApproveCheck"] + "</span>" +
   "<span'>" + item["Ignore"] + "</span>" +
   "</div>");
    }
    count++;
});

return {
    count: count,

};
```

and then add the class to them after they're edited:

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('edit');
}).change(function(){
      $(this).addClass("edited");
    });
```